# How to understand whether potential energy increases or decreases?

Tags: terminology, potential-energy, conventions

I am confused by how to deal with the negative sign in the equation $U=-GMm/r^2$ in the following problem:

> If the distance between two masses is tripled, then the magnitude of the gravitational potential energy is:
>
> A) Increased by a factor of 3
>
> D) Decreased by a factor of 3 -- correct answer

The cause of my confusion is that if r = 1 and you assume U = -1, then when r = 3, U = -1/3.

I am thrown off by the negative sign. Isn't -1/3 actually a larger value than -1? So why is this considered a decrease? Is it because they specify factor of 3, and an increase by factor of 3 would actually be -1*3 = -3?

Furthermore, if potential energy decreases as r gets larger, then why does a pen gain potential energy as you lift it further away from a table and why does the potential energy decrease/convert to kinetic energy when you drop the pen?

I have only taken intro physics, so some of the other potential energy sign convention questions went over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you wrote the equation for $U$ wrong; it should be $r$ instead of $r^2$ in the denominator.  However, that typo isn't what the problem is.

The problem is that you've overlooked the word "magnitude" in the question.  If a negative number is changed to be a different negative number that's closer to zero, then the [magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics)#Real_numbers) of the number has decreased, even though the number itself has increased.

Potential energy does indeed increase as you lift a pen further away from a table, and potential energy does indeed decrease if you drop the pen.

Comment: As an aside, it is clear that the numeric discrepancy is resolved by the fact that $V\propto r^{-1}$, not $r^{-2}$.

Comment: @Danu Yeah, it would have been more sensible to point out the equation error instead of the numeric error.  I edited the answer to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Furthermore, if PE decreases as r gets larger, then why does a pen
>   gain PE as you lift it further away from a table and why does the PE
>   decrease/convert to KE when you drop the pen?

These are two entirely different contexts.

In the first context, the potential energy of the *system* of two objects is considered.

In this context, the magnitude of the gravitational potential energy equals the work that must be done to move the masses 'infinitely' far apart.  Thus, the *larger* the distance between the masses, the *smaller* the work that must be done and, so, the smaller the magnitude of the potential energy.

In the 2nd context, the potential energy of *one* of the objects (the pen) is considered and is defined as the work done to raise the pen from the (arbitrary) *zero of height* to height $h$.

Moreover, in the context of the pen, we consider the change in height to be *small enough* such that the force on the pen is effectively constant.

This potential energy equals the kinetic energy of the pen if it is allowed to fall freely to the zero height.