# Reason for the negative sign in the gravitational potential $-GM/r$?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, conventions

why the gravitational potential comes out to be negative  that is $-GM/r$?
where G is gravitational constant
M is mass of the body
r is position at which the mass has to be brought from infinity.

Comment: More on [sign convention for gravitational potential energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+sign+%5Bconventions%5D+%5Bpotential-energy%5D%5Bnewtonian-gravity%5D).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand whether potential energy increases or decreases?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138739/)

Answer (score 2):

Please read the following definitions:-

> The change in potential energy of the system is defined as the negative of work done by the internal conservative forces of the system.
>   The change in gravitational potential is defined as the ratio of change in gravitational potential energy per unit mass in taking a mass from one point to another.

The negative sign comes from the assumption of defining potential energy of the system as zero when the constituent particles are at a indefinite separation.So if the constituent particles would approach each other then the internal forces(gravitational) do positive work as the gravitational forces always attract.We have defined the change in potential energy as the negative of work done by the internal forces,so as a consequence the negative sign is put in front of 
$GM/r$.

Answer (score 0):

The potential is negative because an external force taking a unit test mass from the chosen zero of potential (infinity) to a position which is $r$ from point mass $M$ and the displacement of the unit test mass are in opposite directions.
So the work done (force times displacement) by the external force per unit test mass between those two positions  (the definition of potential) is negative.

If the zero of potential had been chosen to be at a position $r$ away from point mass $M$ then the potential infinitely far away from the point mass would be positive as the external force and the displacement of the test mass would be in the same direction.